# What is the most efficient way to refresh a table in SQL Server having 15M records from Oracle on daily basis?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I am using a LinkedServer in SQL 2012 and refreshing a table from Oracle 9G using below procedure on daily basis. The current records in the table is 15M and it is increasing every day by 2-3K new records and the old records are also deleting and updating randomly. It takes 7-8 hours to complete this job overnight.Considering the table is already optimized on index level at Oracle side,  What can be the most efficient way to attempt this?
My current process is below :

```
Truncate table SQLTable
Select * into SQLTable from openquery (LinkedServerName,'Select * from OracleTable')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to truncate 15M rows just for 3000-8000 rows changes.

I would consider using an ETL tool like https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/. You can start with a free community edition.

This tool provides a Spoon tool that basically provides graphical interface to create a workflow. With the Pan tool you can execute the file you create using spoon tool. Basically create a batch file with Pan command and provide .ktr file as an argument. Now, this batch file you can schedule using windows task manager or Unix CRON Job.

With this, you can create a workflow, which can look for changes and only insert or update changes.

Comment: I understand and thanks for your response. If we just ignore my use case as of now, is there a more efficient way to pull records through a linked server? am I using the correct procedure?

Comment: I am an Oracle person, haven't worked much in SQLServer. But it seems you can provide any query in the form of text. So you can make your query for oracle more robust and only pull changes from oracle.  e.g. "select * from oracletable where lastupdated>:paramer or created>:parameter " . Now on SQLServer if there is merge query available use that to merge change only instead of truncate.

Comment: there must be some way in the oracle table to identify changes, make it parameterized and create a text query dynamically in SQLServer stored procedure based on data you have in SQL server database table.

Comment: Seems to be a good idea, in Openquery i write Oracle query only. so how do we use Merge in Oracle?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, here is good example of Oracle merge query. https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-merge/